# Extending Long-lived access tokens

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, oauth

I've been reading about the [Removal of offline_access](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/) permission.

My goal is to extend the long-lived access token.

So what I'm trying to do, is refresh the long-lived token before the 60 days expiration, maybe on the 55th to 59th day.

The problem is, the documentation said that **you can only extend short-lived access token**.

However, when I do the solution in [How to handle expired tokens](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/) post, both client-side and server-side auth flows give me the long-lived access token.

So my specific question is, where do I get a new short-lived token?

Once I get this short-lived token, I'll extend it and replace the existing nearly-expired long-lived token, therefore making a seamless experience.

Comment: You can answer your own question and accept it, please do not leave this question formally unanswered as it's somewhat misleading.

Comment: thanks, I posted the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I cannot use the solution in [How to handle expired tokens](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/) because my access_token is not yet expired. As I said, I'll be doing this in 55-59th day, before long-lived token expires.

It seems the user has granted a previous `offline_access` to the application. That's why both client-side and server-side auth flows return the long-lived access token. This happens even if migration is enabled in the app settings. Facebook should also note about this in their documentation. The solution is for the user to revoke the `offline_access` permission.

Hopefully all `offline_access` permissions will be revoked once they force the migration scheduled in May 2, [see developer roadmap](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/).

**Case Closed.** May this post help other users who encounter such rare situations.